# Why Livy session is not found after YARN application succeed?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, livy

Using [pylivy](https://github.com/acroz/pylivy) I create session and download resulting dataframe. The running code itself is not important:

```py
with LivySession.create(self.LIVY_URL, kind=SessionKind.PYSPARK, requests_session=self.requests_session, spark_conf=conf) as session:
    session.run(code)
    return session.download(download_dataframe_name)
```

It works fine in staging environment on small amounts of data. Fail with error on large amounts in production environment:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Server Error for url: https://***:443/gateway/production/livy/sessions/655/statements/1
```

```
{"msg":"Session '655' not found."}
```

Wherein YARN application finished with succeed status in 4 minutes:
[image]

Livy logs looks like:

```
23/11/15 14:06:14 INFO InteractiveSession: Interactive session 656 created [appid: application_1698181251761_0043, owner: knox, proxyUser: Some(e.makrushin), state: idle, kind: pyspark, info: {driverLogUrl=http://***:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e58_1698181251761_0043_01_000001/e.makrushin, sparkUiUrl=http://***/proxy/application_1698181251761_0043/}]
23/11/15 14:09:54 INFO InteractiveSessionManager: Deleting session 656
23/11/15 14:09:54 INFO InteractiveSession: Stopping InteractiveSession 656...
23/11/15 14:09:54 WARN Rpc: [Rpc] Closing RPC channel with 2 outstanding RPCs.
23/11/15 14:09:54 ERROR SessionServlet$: internal error
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.cancel(...)(Unknown Source)
23/11/15 14:09:54 INFO InteractiveSession: Stopped InteractiveSession 656.
23/11/15 14:09:54 INFO InteractiveSessionManager: Deleted session 656
```

It seems the session is deleted before I can download the result. Why might this happen and how to fix it?